# Python/SQLite updating columns

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to update a couple of columns in my SQLite database using:

```
UPDATE db SET Col1 = 0 WHERE Col1 IS NULL;
UPDATE db SET Col2 = 0 WHERE Col2 IS NULL;
```

However this seems to take a very long time to even update one column. I have resorted to using:

```
CASE WHEN Col1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Col1 END
```

in my `SELECT` queries which works a lot quicker, however is there a reason why the `UPDATE` method is so slow? (I only have 670K rows in my database)

NOTE: My computer is fairly high-end and when the `UPDATE` is running, there doesn't seem to be much pressure on my desktops resources.

Comment: How long does the update take? Jon's answer is qualitatively correct, but if you have only ~600 rows I would expect a simple update like this to be faster than a person could perceive. There could be something else going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UPDATE`ing requires starting a transaction, then keeping a write-ahead-log of the changes that the update would make, then ensuring that succeeds before then writing changes back to the main table, and then ensuring all of that completes successfully...

`SELECT`ing is reading then doing a simple "in memory if" to swap the values over for each row... so it's bound to be faster (plus disk reads are almost always a lot faster than disk writes (which a SELECT really doesn't require))...

Comment: @Blackholify on a side note, simpler than `CASE WHEN ...` is to use `COALESCE(col1, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the tools available to do an "explain" on your query :to see what (if any) indexes your sql query is using. if your sql query is resulting in a full table scan over 670K rows, then it could be slowish.

if you are using ubuntu or a similiar based linux distribution, Sqliteman will do this for you.

Comment: Yes I do but I've gone with the `CASE WHEN` method as there's probably no point in `UPDATE`ing those values in my application.